# SVG Height stretching

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm using SVG's as icons in the following way
The SVG's are saved from in Illustrator CC

```
<div class="social">
    <a href=""><img src="img/icon_twitter.svg"></a>
    <a href=""><img src="img/icon_facebook.svg"></a>
</div>
```

This is the CSS. The social div is the wrapper of the 2 's

```
.social {
    position: absolute;
    left: 40px;
    bottom: 40px;
}
.social img {
    width: 50px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Here are the screenshots with the results, The first one is normal ( chrome )
The other one's are weirdly stretched in the height.

**Chrome**

[image]

**Internet Explorer 11**

[image]

**Safari**

[image]

Here's the SVG code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 18.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build     0)  -->
 <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 viewBox="0 0 28.4 28.4" enable-background="new 0 0 28.4 28.4" xml:space="preserve">
<path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M14.2,0C6.4,0,0.1,6.3,0.1,14.1c0,7.8,6.3,14.1,14.1,14.1s14.1-    6.3,14.1-14.1C28.4,6.3,22,0,14.2,0z
     M18,14.1h-2.4c0,3.9,0,8.7,0,8.7h-3.6c0,0,0-4.8,0-8.7h-1.7V11h1.7V9c0-1.4,0.7-    3.7,3.7-3.7l2.7,0v3c0,0-1.6,0-2,0
    c-0.3,0-0.8,0.2-0.8,0.8V11h2.8L18,14.1z"/>
</svg>
```

## Solution

In my CSS i only specified width: 50px; for the image element that holds the SVG.
I also had to specify a height: 50px; It's working now!

Comment: Do the image files have a viewBox and preserveAspectRatio set? If not you probably need to set them. Showing us the files themselves would help if you're still stuck.

Comment: I added the SVG code to the question! Thanks

Comment: Try adding preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" to the `<svg>` element.

Comment: Aha found the solution... in my CSS i had to add height: 50px; as well, i didn't specify the height, only the width. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

In your SVG remove the `height and width`attr this will make it responsive

read more at [MAKING SVGS RESPONSIVE WITH CSS](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/08/19/making-svgs-responsive-with-css/)

Comment: There is no height or width, I'm adding the SVG code to my question

Comment: There is always a `height` and a `width` if you are using a `mac`open the svg with `chrome` and press `cmd` + `alt`+ `u` to view the `view-source` then copy it and remove the `height`

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

#### I also have to specify the height attribute in my CSS

In my css i was had

```
width: 50px;
```

But you also have to specify the height. It's not preserving the aspect from itself.
Thanks everyone!